# Group Textbox and table in winform report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services

**BackGround:**
I'm creating a report through Visual Studio 2012, using winforms.  My report includes 2 tables, both with a textbox above it with the name of the table.  I know to group table rows together , you use the "Keep Together" property, which fixed my original issue of only the first row being shown and the rest pages later.

**Problem:**
However, when I export the PDF, for example with the first table, it shows the textbox with the name of the table like it's supposed to, but the table doesn't show for 3 pages.

**Question:**
How do I keep my controls together in the report without potential overlapping or large spaces in between each control?

**Margin Setting Code (XML Snippet)**

```
 <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
```

**.cs Code Snippet**

```
 private void ExportPDF(LocalReport report, string filename)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportPageSettings rptPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();

            string width = "";
            double tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.PaperSize.Width) * .01;
            width = tmp.ToString("#0.00",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string height = "";
            tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.PaperSize.Height) * .01;
            height = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string topMargin = "";
            tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Top) * .01;
            topMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string bottomMargin = "";
            tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Bottom) * .01;
            topMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string rightMargin = "";
            tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Right) * .01;
            topMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string leftMargin = "";
            tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Left) * .01;
            topMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

            string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><PageWidth>" + width + "</PageWidth><PageHeight>" + height + "</PageHeight><MarginTop>" + topMargin + "</MarginTop><MarginLeft>" + leftMargin + "</MarginLeft><MarginRight>" + rightMargin + "</MarginRight><MarginBottom>" + bottomMargin + "</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

            m_streams[0].Position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m_streams[0].Length; i++)
            {
                fs.WriteByte((byte)m_streams[0].ReadByte());
            }

            fs.Close();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the margin settings and whether you are exporting in portrait vs. landscape (depending on the width of the table)?

Comment: @dbagley I edited my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bottomMargin, rightMargin, and leftMargin were set to empty string:

```
        string bottomMargin = "";
        tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Bottom) * .01;
        bottomMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

        string rightMargin = "";
        tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Right) * .01;
        rightMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";

        string leftMargin = "";
        tmp = ((double)rptPageSettings.Margins.Left) * .01;
        leftMargin = tmp.ToString("#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused on what you're asking.  The code you supplied is what I put in my question (unless your intention was to show what needs to be changed) .  Bottom, right, and left margin are already initialized to an empty string.  If I set the topMargin to an empty string for each block, pdf looks very similar.  I'm not getting errors.

Comment: I am editing your code and my answer to better explain.  Sorry about that.